# Creating an instance of the base class of a class using generics

Tags: java, generics, subclass, abstract, superclass

In my Java project I have an abstract class using a generics type. My class is extended and implemented by some concrete subclasses. My source code is something like this:

```
class Metrics<T extends Dataset>
{
    public float evaluate(T dataset, Entity x, Entity y);
}

class MetricsType1 extends Metrics<DatasetType1>
{
    public float evaluate(DatasetType1 dataset, Entity x, Entity y);
}

class MetricsType2 extends Metrics<DatasetType2>
{
    public float evaluate(DatasetType2 dataset, Entity x, Entity y);
}
```

In my main application I use my classes in this way:

```
Metrics<DatasetType1> metrics1 = new MetricsType1();
Metrics<DatasetType2> metrics2 = new MetricsType2();
```

I would like to use the same reference "metrics" instead of having two different references "metrics1" and "metrics" so that I could instance my "metrics" reference with a MetricsType1 or a MetricsType2 class without having to write two separate references.

In particular I would like to write something like this:

```
Metrics metrics = null;
metrics = new MetricsType1();
// ...
metrics = new MetricsType2();
```

Obviously the Java interpreter gives me a warning telling me I should use a parameter for the generics of the class Metrics.

How could I handle this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use wildcards:

```
Metrics<?> metrics;
```

or, if you ant to be more specific:

```
Metrics<? extends Dataset> metrics;
```

In this particular case, those are both synonyms, as `Metrics` is defined so that `T extends Dataset`.

Notice, however, that with this definition the `evaluate` method *cannot be called directly*. You will have to cast the object to a concrete subclass to do it.

Comment: The OP should be able to cast the references and use the correct evaluate methods though right? The erasure is not known but the subclasses are straight subclasses and can be checked with instanceof.

Comment: Yes, of course, casting to a subtype allows `evaluate` to be called. Answer updated to reflect that.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I need to call the evaluate method of my metrics from the method of another class. I have something like: public <T extends Dataset> Network build(T dataset, Metrics<T> metrics). How could I call metrics.evaluate in this method without referring to Metrics subclasses?

Comment: If you have a `Metrics<T>`, there is no problem with `evaluate`. The problem arises from the wildcard. See this for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 0):

You want `Metrics<?>`.
If there is a common base type, you can also use `Metrics<? extends CommonType>`.